# How to generate a new type in C#

Tags: c#, il

I really want to generate a new type at runtime.  Essentially, I want to create types that look something like this:

```
public class MySpecial123
{
    public Func<int, DateTime, int> salesVectorCalc; // field

    public int CallSalesVectorCalculation(int i, DateTime d)
    (
        return salesVectorCalc(i, d);
    )
}
```

Some of the types will vary based on user/DB inputs, so I can't really accomplish it any other way then to create the type at runtime.  There is also more complexity, but I wanted to make my question simple so I am only asking the essential questions here.  I will need to do more generation that just what you see here.

I was thinking it would be cool to use `Reflection.Emit`, but then I realized it might be easier to generate the code and compile all in memory.  Does anyone know which is better?  I would really like to see an example of how to do either one of these.

Comment: You shouldn't want that actually.

Answer (score 5):

When you say "generate a type at runtime" it sounds as though you are asking for *dynamic typing*.

In C# 4.0 it's done simply with the dynamic keyword.

However, you also describe something akin to code generation - if this is more what you are after, why not use something like T4 Templates to generate your types in a "pre-compile" phase?

Comment: Dynamic lets you *use* dynamic types. It does not help with *creating* them.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty easy to generate your code as a string and then dynamically compile it to an in-memory assembly. You can then call your methods and access your fields by either:

- Using reflection
- Using the *dynamic* keyword
- Casting to an interface / base class (if your new class inherits from one)

Code:

```
public static Assembly Compile(string source)
{
    var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<String, String> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
    var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters();

    compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
    compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.dll");
    compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
    compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.Linq.dll");
    compilerParameters.CompilerOptions = "/t:library";
    compilerParameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

    var result = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, source);
    if (result.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (CompilerError error in result.Errors)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("ERROR Line {0:000}: {1}", error.Line, error.ErrorText);
        }
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        return result.CompiledAssembly;
    }
}
```